# Why is "Nico-nico-nii" not allowed on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

I flagged a post for moderator attention, with this custom reason:

> *"Nico-nico-nii!"*

But then it was **declined.**

> [image: Flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention.]

Now I am curious: **Why is "Nico-nico-nii" not allowed here?**

---

"Nico-nico-nii" is a very famous anime reference: it is the well-known catchphrase that is used by Nico Yazawa from the anime *Love Live*.  If you want to learn more, see [here.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/56142/what-does-nico-nico-nii-mean)

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the concept of Stack Exchange... we don't send people to Google, we expect Google send people to us.

Comment: While you make edits, it would be nice to explain what you are talking about...

Comment: Thanks, but you still didn't explained what you meant while flagging something with this reason (I don't understand japanese).

Comment: Uh...maybe next time when flagging, try to rely on communicating what the actual problems are by ways of more than weird memes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, [**we hate fun**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284390/241919), or to be exact: random, nonsensical, meaningless fun.

While *I* got the reference since I follow anime and manga in general, using a mod flag to... I don't know, getting attention?.. is certainly wasting the mod's time. I don't even know what the mods are expected to do *to the post* with such custom flag reason.

Moreover, Stack Exchange is a vast international community. Everyone is not expected to know every culture/meme in the world. Asking a mod (or even users) to decipher the meaning of something without context is just frowned upon.

Answer (score 6):

It is not easy to understand what you are talking about, nor what you flagged (question, or answer). But I think you misused the custom flag feature.

The custom flag should be used when the reason you want to flag a post is not in the list.

[image: custom flag]

Then you should write what was wrong in the post you want to flag. And **the custom reason must be understandable without going to do further research on Google**.

For example:

> This post is wrong because XXX.

Answer (score 3):

In general, mods look at the reasons for the flag separately so if the wrong flag reason is used it will be declined especially if the spam flag or rude flag is thrown as they have extra weight. In this case the flag did not make sense so it was declined. We're not going to google search to try to figure out what the flag is supposed to mean.

Comment: @MaikaOshikkoSakuranomiya it does not matter which mod handled the flag. That information is never displayed for a reason.