# What makes a good use of the phrase "Nico-nico-nii" here?

Tags: support

I see that using the phrase "Nico-nico-nii" is not allowed here due to various reasons, like [this.](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/533/why-is-nico-nico-nii-not-allowed-on-stack-exchange)  So, are there any ways to use this phrase in a good/valid way here?

Comment: Why do you think there is a "good use" *required* to begin with? It's not that it isn't "allowed" here, it's just that it seems to be random nonsense, especially when *not* coupled with any other relevant context. That meta question is about using it as a sole message in a flag, where it makes absolutely no sense to spout random memes. However, extending this to the general prohibition of a specific phrase really makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

In what circumstances would that be something that could help answer a question or solicit discussion? The only time I could see this being valid on MusicFans is if it were part of the lyrics of a song, but that hasn't been the way we've seen this being used in the past. **That's a phrase that simply has little potential to be constructive** on this (and most other) Stack Exchange sites.

Realize this: **Stack Exchange is not an entertainment website.** At its core, it is a Question-and-Answer Database, meant for *serious discussion and empirical research.* Humor and inside references are usually not acceptable within the site's important functions, such as Questions, Answers, Edits, Flagging, Votes-to-Close, and others. Comments and chat are less restrictive, but there's still an expectation of not simply posting troll garbage on the site.

If you can find a way to be comedic within the site's intended functions, by all means, be my guest. Personally, I love seeing that human element expressed on the site. But that doesn't mean I'm okay with random junk in the comments or (ahem) clogging up the moderators' flag review queues, and I think the community is 100% behind me on this one. **Take your anime references elsewhere, please.**

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange is in English. This sentence is not so there is no specific way to "use" this phrase here, except it's something related to Music Fans.